# SPARQL query containing 'coalesce' returns no result on rdflib-endpoint.SparqlEndpoint()

Tags: sparql

I am running a SparqlEndpoint from this package: https://pypi.org/project/rdflib-endpoint/

I define a graph,
g = Graph(), then
g.parse() a number of .ttl files and create the endpoint with SparqlEndpoint(graph=g).
Then I use uvicorn.run(app, ...) to expose the endpoint on my local machine.

I can successfully run this simple sparql statement to query for keywords:

```
PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>
SELECT 
?keyword
WHERE { ?subj dcat:keyword ?keyword }
```

However, as soon as I add a coalesce statement, the query does not return results any more:

```
PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>
SELECT 
?keyword
(coalesce(?keyword, "xyz") as ?foo) 
WHERE { ?subj dcat:keyword ?keyword }
```

I tried something similar on wikidata which has no problems:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
(coalesce(?itemLabel, 2) as ?foo)
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146. # Must be of a cat
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
}
```

Is there maybe an issue with the rdflib-endpoint.SparqlEndpoint()?
The server debug output for the keywords query looks ok to me.

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:43942 - "GET /sparql?format=json&query=%0APREFIX+dcat%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fdcat%23%3E%0ASELECT+%0A%3Fkeyword%0A%28coalesce%28%3Fkeyword%2C+%22xyz%22%29+as+%3Ffoo%29+%0AWHERE+%7B+%3Fsubj+dcat%3Akeyword+%3Fkeyword+%7D%0ALIMIT+10%0A HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Putting COALESCE in the WHERE clause does not solve the problem:

```
PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>
SELECT
?keyword
?foo
WHERE {
?subj dcat:keyword ?keyword
BIND(coalesce(?keyword, 2) as ?foo)
}
```

TIA

Comment: what happens if you put the `coalesce` into a `BIND` instead of the projection part? I.e. `SELECT ... ?foo { ...  BIND(coalesce(?itemLabel, 2) as ?foo)}` ?

Comment: @foobar Have you solved this one?